# Android Viewpager Disappear after TranslateAnimation

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have `onScrollChanged` method for my `ScrollView` and if the `y coordinate` changes `onScrollChanged` method run.I call in `onScrollChanged` method either `moveStuffOnScreen` and `moveStuffOffScreen` for every pixel. **TranslateAnimation** run over and over in these methods. After too many calls on some Android devices my other views(espically **Viewpagers**) disappear suddenly.(Devices like Samsung Galaxy Ace, Samsung Galaxy Mini).How can I avoid this issue?

```
private class TopBarAnimationOnScrollListener extends ScrollListener {

            @Override
            public void onScrollChanged(int x, int y, int oldX, int oldY) {


                      // method calls
            }
    }
    void moveStuffOnScreen()
    {
        if (_isMovingUpToBeOnScreen)
            return;
        _isMovingUpToBeOnScreen = true;

        resetTopBarPositionToInitial();

        TranslateAnimation translateAnimationOn = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, initialRelativeLayoutHeaderHomeSmallTop - relativeLayoutHeaderHomeSmall.getHeight(),
                        initialRelativeLayoutHeaderHomeSmallTop);
        translateAnimationOn.setFillAfter(true);
        translateAnimationOn.setDuration(300);

        relativeLayoutHeaderHomeSmall.setAnimation(translateAnimationOn);

    }
    void moveStuffOffScreen() {
        if (!_isMovingUpToBeOnScreen)
            return;
        _isMovingUpToBeOnScreen = false;

        resetTopBarPositionToInitial();

        TranslateAnimation translateAnimationOff = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, initialRelativeLayoutHeaderHomeSmallTop, initialRelativeLayoutHeaderHomeSmallTop
                        - relativeLayoutHeaderHomeSmall.getHeight());
        translateAnimationOff.setFillAfter(true);
        translateAnimationOff.setDuration(300);
        relativeLayoutHeaderHomeSmall.setAnimation(translateAnimationOff);

    }
```